# Might Lua's length operator return a negative index?

Tags: lua

The, well, [special specification of Lua's length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5) made me wonder whether Lua would be "allowed" to return a negative value in a situation like

```
#{[-5]=1,[-1]=3}
```

It says:

> The length of a table `t` is defined to be any integer index `n` such that `t[n]` is not **`nil`** and `t[n+1]` is **`nil`**;

`n=-5` and `n=-1` would meet this criterion in my example, right?

> moreover, if `t[1]` is **`nil`**, `n` can be zero.

Right, it *can* be zero, but it's not guaranteed, right?

> For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a given n, its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value.

This isn't the case here, so it doesn't apply.

> If the array has "holes" (that is, **`nil`** values between other non-nil values), then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a **`nil`** value (that is, it may consider any such **`nil`** value as the end of the array).

This is the case here, so again, `n=-5` and `n=-1` would be valid return values, right?

Can I be entirely certain that Lua always returns 0 for the example table, or any other table containing only negative indices?  If (hypothetically) I'd be writing a Lua interpreter and would return either of those values, would I be conforming with the specifications?

**Edit**

Obviously, the way Lua is implemented, it does not return negative values.  I felt the length operator is somewhat underdocumented and I see that Lua 5.2's documentation has changed.  It now says:

> Unless a `__len` metamethod is given, the length of a table `t` is only defined if the table is a *sequence*, that is, the set of its positive numeric keys is equal to *{1..n}* for some integer *n*. In that case, *n* is its length. Note that a table like
>
> ```
>   {10, 20, nil, 40}
> ```
>
> is not a sequence, because it has the key `4` but does not have the key `3`.

So, it now talks about *positive* numeric keys, that's much clearer.  I'm left wiser but not totally happy with the documentation.  When it says the "length is only defined if the table is a sequence", it should also state that even if the table is not a sequence a value is returned, but the *behavior* is undefined.  Also, this table looks pretty much like a sequence:

```
a = setmetatable(
  {0},
  {
    __index = function(t,k)
      return k < 10 and k or nil 
    end
  }
)
i = 1
while a[i] do
  print(a[i])
  i = i+1
end
--[[ prints:
0
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
]]
print(#a)
-- prints: 1
```

However, this is becoming nitpicking as it's pretty clear that it wouldn't make sense to take into account what mess `__index` might make.  And Stackoverflow is certainly not the place to complain about documentation that could be more precise.

Comment: Only positive integer indices are taking into account.  Negative, fractional and non-numeric indices may contain anything without affecting the length returned by `#` operator.  Probably, Lua manual  should be changed to be a bit more clear on this.

Comment: "... it should also state that even if the table is not a sequence a value is returned, but the *behavior* is undefined" -- If the behavior is undefined, all bets are off and it doesn't necessarily make sense to say that a value is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noted, the specification of the length operator has changed between 5.1 and 5.2.

> Can I be entirely certain that Lua always returns 0 for the example table, or any other table containing only negative indices?

You can for the current reference implementation, which ensures that for `ilen` defined

```
function ilen (xs) 
    local i=0
    while xs[i+1] do i=i+1 end
    return i 
end
```

we always have `#xs >= ilen(xs)` - see the definition of luaH_getn in [the `ltable.c` source](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ltable.c.html).  But the specification now deliberately does not promise this behaviour: a conformant implementation can return `nil` or raise an exception for attempts to find the length of tables that are not sequences.

Answer (score 0):

From the text in reference link. The answer is NO.

I think your confusing the fact that if a NIL is found then the length of the table is deemed to be position the NIL was found -1.

Therefore if t(1) is NIL then 1 - 1 = 0 so the table length is 0.

If the length of a table was 5  then the next position or t(6) IS or WOULD BE NIL

```
The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n such that t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil; moreover, if t[1] is nil, n can be zero.
```

Comment: By this logic, if I find a nil at index 100, then as an implementor I would be allowed to return 99. That's clearly not accurate.

Comment: Isn't that what is being implied? because if you found a NIL at 100 then return would be 99 and this fulfils the following "The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n such that t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil"

Comment: No, it doesn't, because for `n=99` `t[n]` *is* `nil`, but it's required that it is *not* `nil`.

Comment: Thats not what you wrote in the above QUOTE: "By this logic, if I find a nil at index 100, then as an implementor I would be allowed to return 99" which is n=99 and n+1 is 100

Comment: Yes, this was meant as an example for the logic of your answer (as I understood it). I think you got the logic in reverse. It's clear that the index following the last one should return nil, but Lua has no real concept of a last index, it determines the length of a table using this cited logic and can come to different conclusions for tables with identical content. You can go [here](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo), paste this code and see that the content is identical but first the determined length is 3, then it's 1:
`a={1,nil,3}
print(a[1],a[2],a[3],#a)
a={1,[3]=3}
print(a[1],a[2],a[3],#a)`

Comment: @ThomasW it's basically undefined behavior. Programming in Lua also says: if you don't use a table with contiguous values from 1 to n (which all have to be different from nil), then you should expect garbage from all built-in functionality that treats tables like arrays (which includes the length operator).